# Access shared folder that exists in VM or local machine from azure cloud service(web-role)

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-virtual-machine, webrole

I have an Asp.Net web role which is running in Azure Cloud service.
Now I have created a virtual machine in Azure data center.
And also I have created a shared folder for storing my files(.xls,.csv .. files).
how can I access the shared folder files that are exists in the VM from my web-role ?

thanks

Arun.

Answer (score 2):

Shared folders are mainly for on-premise environment and in cloud you would have to think quite different. In cloud environment, a machine is placed behind a very tightly closed network system and any port you will open in your VM will be configured for external user through firewall. Accessing a shared folder would require you to enable file sharing in your machine first and the configuring proper ports. Similar configuration is needed on other Cloud Service VM as well which is more complex. **The fact is when you are in cloud you should think beyond shared folder approach.**

What you really need is to use cloud storage i.e. Windows Azure Blob Storage to share content between multiple machines. Price wise it is about ~10 cents/GB/Month and if you keep your VM and Azure Storage in same datacenter there is no bandwidth cost. Once configured your Azure VM and Azure Cloud service can access the Azure Blob storage very easily over HTTP/HTTPS. Learn more about Azure Storage [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/storage/).